# How can I remove single length character from a string in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

E.g.
Input string: "I am an Engineer"
Expected Output: "am an Engineer"

Answer (score 4):

You can use `stuff()`:

```
select stuff('I am an Engineer',1,1,'')
```

returns: `am an Engineer`

If you want to trim spaces on the left side of the string as well, you can use `ltrim()`

```
select ltrim(stuff('I am an Engineer',1,1,''))
```

returns: `am an Engineer`

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/BQHYR97427

---

If you want to remove the first instance of a character in a string, you can use `charindex()` with `stuff()` within a case expression to make sure the character is in the string like so:

```
declare @str varchar(32) = 'I am an Engineer';
declare @char char(1) = 'n'

select str = case when charindex(@char,@str) > 0 
          then stuff(@str,charindex(@char,@str),1,'') 
          else @str 
          end
```

returns: `I am a Engineer`

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/UZCVR72854

Comment: The Position of Single length character will be dynamic. So this will not work.

Comment: @Er_Faizan . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you have another question, then ask *another* question.  If you edit this question you are likely to invalidate the answer.

Comment: I can have input string like this also in my column: "abcd xyz d pqrs d wxy"

Answer (score 2):

Tried using the `STRING_SPLIT` function and `XML`, you can give it a try

> Starting from SQL 2016

```
SELECT VALUE + ' '  FROM STRING_SPLIT ('abcd xyz d pqrs d wxy',' ') WHERE LEN(Value) > 1
FOR XML PATH ('')
```

### Result

abcd xyz pqrs wxy

> For lower versions of SQL you may need to create a function to do the process

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitString(@String NVARCHAR(MAX), @Delimiter CHAR(1))    
RETURNS @Results TABLE (Result NVARCHAR(MAX))    
AS    
BEGIN  
 DECLARE @Index INT    
 DECLARE @Data NVARCHAR(MAX)    

 SELECT @Index = 1    
 IF @String IS NULL RETURN  

 WHILE @Index != 0    
 BEGIN      
  SELECT @Index = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String)    
  IF @Index != 0    
   SELECT @Data = LEFT(@String, @Index - 1)    
  ELSE    
   SELECT @Data = @String    
  INSERT INTO @Results(Result) VALUES (@Data)    
  SELECT @String = RIGHT(@String, LEN(@String) - @Index)    
  IF LEN(@String) = 0 BREAK    
 END    
 RETURN  
END
```

Comment: I'm using Sql Server 2014. String_Split function is not supported in 2014 version.

Comment: @Er_Faizan you can create a `splitstring` function and use that in the query

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>[RIGHT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql)</kbd> Function

```
SELECT RIGHT('Your String',len('Your String')-1)
```

Comment: The position of single length character is dynamic in my string. the String can be like this also : "abcd xyz d pqrs i wxy"

Comment: If string is like so ` "abcd xyz d pqrs i wxy" ` then what will be expected output

Answer (score 0):

Why not just start always at position 2 of the string ? i.e.:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100)
SET @string = 'I am an Engineer'

SELECT LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@string, 2, LEN(@string) ))
```

...will return: 'am an Engineer'